# why got a blank drop-down menue of comboBox in C# WPF visual studio 2013 eventhough I have initialized it

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, data-binding, combobox

I would like to design a comboBox in C# WPF VS2013 on win 7 like

```
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742404%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#guidelines
```

My xaml code:

```
  <ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
             SelectedItem="{Binding MyObject}"
             Margin="5"  ItemsSource="{Binding MyObjList}" 
             DisplayMemberPath="Name"
   />
   // MyObjList is a list of MyObject
   public class MyObject
   {
        int id; 
        string Name;
    }
```

Although I have initialized MyObjList in C# code behind it, the dropdown comboBox meue is blank.

I have search some related posts

[How to show text in combobox when no item selected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8064133/how-to-show-text-in-combobox-when-no-item-selected)

[WPF ComboBox bad blank value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442867/wpf-combobox-bad-blank-value)

But, none of them work for me.

Could anybody point out where I made a mistake ?

Comment: For binding to work, you need properties. Your MyObject only has member variables and they aren't even public. Change it to: public int id {get;set;} and public string Name {get;set;}. You didn't show the code for MyObjList but I'm assuming it has the same issue.

Comment: As mentioned, note that member variables are private unless specified. A good practice is to specify `private` even though it is the default.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your question was already given by [J.H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2141972/j-h) in his comments.  Let me elaborate a bit.

**Mistakes in your code:**

- Members of the class `MyObject` should be `Properties` and not fields.
- Also, the same with members of the `ViewModel` (I hope you have defined that as fields)

**Here is the working solution:**

MyObject.cs

```
public class MyObject
{
    //int id;
    //string Name;

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

MyViewModel.cs

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyObject> MyObjList { get; set; }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    ObservableCollection<MyObject> objs = new ObservableCollection<MyObject>();
    objs.Add(new MyObject() { id = 1, Name = "Someone1" });
    objs.Add(new MyObject() { id = 2, Name = "Someone2" });
    this.DataContext = new MyViewModel() { MyObjList = objs };
 }
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
             SelectedItem="{Binding MyObject}"
             Margin="5"  ItemsSource="{Binding MyObjList}" 
             DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
```

Comment: You need to properly implement INotifyPropertyChanged on your MyViewModel class also.

Comment: @Taterhead.  Yes. . But that's not our intention here. Anyway, I will make a note.  Thanks for that.